# NODE_PATH or any module alias with node-server on zeit/now.sh

Tags: vercel

Using `@​now/node-server`, I'm trying to achieve this:

```
const myLocalLibrary = require('@src/lib/myLocalLibrary');
```

Instead of

```
const myLocalLibrary = require('../../../lib/myLocalLibrary');
```

The problem is that I have tried multiple things that won't work, including:

#### Setting `NODE_PATH=src` and using `require('src/...`

Does not work because setting NODE_PATH as env has no effect

#### Patching require using module-alias (https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)

Works locally, fails on Zeit because node can't find any files using the module.

I used:

```
require("module-alias").addAlias("~", __dirname);
```

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: seems it is not possible according to the official Github repo https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/342

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/configuration/#build.env)

```
    "build": {
     "env": {
        "NODE_PATH": "src/"
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your solution fails to build on ZEIT Now might be that it
only works runtime, and Now needs to resolve the paths at build time. You can try using [babel-plugin-root-import](https://github.com/entwicklerstube/babel-plugin-root-import#readme) like [described here](https://whoisryosuke.com/blog/2018/nextjs-tip-relative-es6-modules/) instead.

Or if you just want to use absolute imports with [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) and [ZEIT Now](https://zeit.co/now), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234811/use-absolute-imports-in-next-js-app-deployed-with-zeit-now).