# Use absolute imports in Next.js app deployed with ZEIT Now

Tags: next.js, vercel

In the Next.js 9 tutorial the suggested way to [import shared components](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/using-shared-components/using-the-header-component) is by relative paths, like

```js
import Header from '../components/Header';
```

I want to use absolute imports, like

```js
import Header from 'components/Header';
```

How do I make this work both locally and when I [deploy using the Now CLI](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/deploying-a-nextjs-app)?

---

Using the suggested setup from the tutorial, my project structure is:

```
my-project
├── components
├── pages
└── package.json
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Next.js 9.4 and later

If you're using Next.js 9.4 or later, see [Black's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61780091/2054731).

---

## Next.js 9.3 and earlier

There are [different ways](https://whoisryosuke.com/blog/2018/nextjs-tip-relative-es6-modules/) of achieving this, but one way – that requires no additional dependencies and not too much config – is to [set the environment variable `NODE_PATH`](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/342#issuecomment-264744094) to the current directory, i.e. `NODE_PATH=.`.

### 1. Make it work locally

I think the easiest way to set `NODE_PATH=.` when running the dev/build scripts in your `package.json` locally (e.g. `$ npm run dev` or `$ yarn dev`), is to add it to each script in `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "NODE_PATH=. next",
  "build": "NODE_PATH=. next build",
  "start": "next start"
},
```

### 2. Make it work when you deploy

When you deploy to [ZEIT Now](https://zeit.co/now), `NODE_PATH` must be set in a different way.

You can add a [Deployment Configuration](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/advanced/configuration) by adding a `now.json` file (it should be in the same directory as your `package.json`). If you don't have a `now.json` file already, create it and add the following contents:

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "build": {
    "env": {
      "NODE_PATH": "."
    }
  }
}
```

This tells Now to use `NODE_PATH=.` when buildnig your app (see [build.env](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/advanced/configuration#build.env)).

(It also tells Now that we use [Now platform version](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/advanced/platform/overview/#versioning) 2 which is currently the newest version (see [version](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/advanced/configuration#version)). Omitting the version will give you a warning when you deploy using `$ now`.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I haven't seen this documented clearly anyplace else—I found that the [webpack resolver solution](https://whoisryosuke.com/blog/2018/nextjs-tip-relative-es6-modules/) kept failing on Now.

One small tweak I made to this answer: since I was already setting some other values in a `.env` file, I included `NODE_PATH="."` there. Then, I use the `dotenv` library and call `require('dotenv').config()` at the top of a root-level `next.config.js` file. This sets the value without modifying the script commands in `package.json`.

Comment: I also added `jsconfig.json`: `{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "components": ["./components/"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}`

Comment: I use this solution but some recent  package update created some incompatibility with this solution. I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/q/61857093/2700303. Now every page renders blank and a json parser error appears at the javascript console.

Answer (score 4):

In Next.js 9.4 it is possible to do it by adding the `baseUrl` config to `jsconfig.json` (JS projects) or `tsconfig.json` (TS projects).

```json
// jsconfig.json or tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

This will allow imports from the root directory. It also integrates well with IDE such as VS Code. See [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases#absolute-imports-and-module-path-aliases) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm using NextJS 9.4. also and still had to add NODE_PATH to my .env.production file to make my gitlab pipeline runner work (docker executor with node12-alpine image). Several different ways of setting the webpack modules-alias in next.config.js did not work. My local build passed without setting NODE_PATH or configuring module resolution in next's-config while having set the baseUrl in tsconfig.json.

I would love to know how to set the alias properly through the webpack configuration instead of letting NextJs do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

Change web pack configuration:

```
//next.config.js file
module.exports = {  
    webpack(config) {
      config.resolve.modules.push(__dirname)
      return config;
    },
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
import TopBar from 'components/TopBar' // for components
import "public/baseLine.css" // for any public resources
```