# Use absolute imports in nextJs App on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, next.js

I follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57234812/2700303) to configure NextJs to use absolute paths, like this:

```
//package.json:
...
"scripts": {
  "dev": "NODE_PATH=. next",
  "build": "NODE_PATH=. next build",
  "start": "next start"
 },
```

NodeJs, npm and nextJs app are up to date both on windows and Linux.

It works on Linux, but when i try to build on a Windows, it fails with the error

```
'NODE_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

*Update*

I find out that npm is just running SO scripts, so in windows, the equivalent for:

```
NODE_PATH=. next
```

wold be:

```
set NODE_PATH=. & next
```

But doesn't work because the command set does not affect the context of the second command

```
set X=1 & echo %X% returns
%X% //for first run. doesn't consider it a variable because doesn't know her
1 //for second run
```

Can't figure out how to overcame this last problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works from outside:

```
>set NODE_PATH=.
>npm run dev
```

Should be some better solution somewhere